# What version of "One o clock Jump" is the one in "a great day in Harlem" documentary?

Tags: jazz

At 0:40 of the documentary *A Great Day in Harlem*, we hear "One O'Clock Jump" by Count Basie Orchestra:

http://youtu.be/SvvjIuAdGqw

What year is this specific version of "One O'Clock Jump"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this version is from 1957, a live recording Count Basie did at the Newport Jazz Festival with his Orchestra. It can be found on Youtube [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yrsR2pMKoa8). According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Count_Basie_at_Newport), Basie's *At Newport* album, on which this version appears, was recorded on July 7, 1957, and the album was released in early November of the same year.

Fun fact about this recording: according to [all](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_O%27Clock_Jump) of [these](http://www.welwyn11.freeserve.co.uk/LY_countB.htm) different [sources](http://www.freddiegreen.org/discog_cbo_date.html), the original recording Count Basie's "One O'Clock Jump" was done on July 7, 1937, meaning that this historic performance was the 20th anniversary of the original recording.